# Morphological OPEN over a height map in python

Tags: python, opencv, mathematical-morphology

I'm trying to clean up a height map that I imported into a Python array, this file has some almost spherical bumps and some spikes.

A height map is a structured 3D point cloud, where the image grey level is in fact the z coordinate.

I want to use a morphological open filter to keep the spherical bumps and clean out the spikes. In OpenCV I only found examples where the structuring element is a disk, which doesn't work with my file. Is it possible to create a semi-spherical structuring element and apply morphologyEx with it? Or do I need to look into something like PCL that is more 3D oriented?
Just as a quick example, in my 3D height map I have something like this:

[image]

And I want to use a half sphere to round up the bumps and remove the small peak on the top. The structuring element would be like this:

[image]

The size of the half sphere needs to be adapted to the size of the bumps in the image of course.

Comment: You can try another [shape](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gac2db39b56866583a95a5680313c314ad) and aslo it is possible to create it manually, For example a square will be a numpy array with 1 in all the elements. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) you can check what is generated with each shape

Comment: All the examples use a 2d shape where all the values are 1, I need to know if I can create a structuring element in the z axis direction using other values then 1, arranged as the values of a projected half sphere, something like:

Comment: As far as I know, morphologyEx is for 2D images only, and does dilate and erode and the structuring element is binary (1 or 0) so I think you will have to create something manually

Comment: @PedroFerreira I continue here from my answer (which I'm going to delete now): So, you work with images!? Images are 2D data. I repeat myself: Edit your question, provide example images - or if you actually have 3D data, provide examples for those - and show, what you want to achieve! It remains quite unclear from your textual explanations, what you want to do.

Comment: @HansHirse They are height maps... a height map is a structured 3D point cloud file. The level of grey is the z coordinate over the xy plane. A lot of the clean up can be done using 2D tools and it works very well.